How can I improve my multiplayer game code using Fishnet?
I'm exploring the area of ​​multiplayer development using Unity, and I'm using Fishnet for that.
I have had a lot of difficulty learning how it works. The documentation hasn't helped me much and the tutorial videos are complicated for me.
In my multiplayer shooter game, after a week of studying and trying, I managed to make the shot when hitting a player so that I could update his HUD and show his life.
However, it seemed like so much code for so little that I'm wondering if the code is correct and if I could have done it in a better way that I don't know about.
This is my Bullet.cs script for bullets (shooted by a player):
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.TryGetComponent<PlayerController>(out PlayerController playerController))
    {
        playerController.TakeDamage(playerController);
    }

    Server_DestroyBullet();
}

[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
public void Server_DestroyBullet()
{
    InstanceFinder.ServerManager.Despawn(gameObject);
    DestroyInstance();
}

[ObserversRpc]
public void DestroyInstance()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

And this is a part of PlayerController.cs player script:
[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
public void TakeDamage(PlayerController script)
{
    script.healthPoints--;
    UpdateLifeDisplay(script.Owner, script.healthPoints.ToString());
}

[TargetRpc]
void UpdateLifeDisplay(NetworkConnection conn, string value)
{
    HUDController.lifeText.text = value;
}

All of this is used to check whether the bullet hit the player and modify a Canvas text. Could I have done it a better way?

There might be some misunderstanding from your part on how multiplayer works. There are no games with other players. Unless you are playing a turn-based game or split-screen game, you are always alone and other players are simulated. There is nobody else with you. Depending on authority settings, the server dictates or limits certain things (for example StarCraft 1 had shared authority since there was no server, anyone became host after the host was defeated), Deathmatch games (Unreal Toruname, Quake etc.) use server-only authority (for health or bullets). Everything is replicated to clients.

The points is, in such cases, any modification that the client should see will have 2 functions: a server side and a client side one. Also, when you issue a command on a fully authoritative server game, absolutely no other player will know your command (not even chat). You, as a client, send whatever data (movement, chat etc.) to the server and then the server broadcasts it to each client. When you see other players in games, that's just an illusion. It's all on your PC, replicated from the server data being sent to you. Clients don't directly talk to you (except on other authority settings).

Why does it "seem like so much code"? You have an engine event for collision: OnTriggerEnter(). You have the bullet workflow where it gets destroyed on the server and clients Server_DestroyBullet() and DestroyInstance(). And then you have the health points handling in TakeDamage() and replication to the client UpdateLifeDisplay(). This is a normal workflow in network replication. You did the code just fine, so good job! There are no other shortcuts. Another approach can be to maybe send "linked" or related data in the same function as multiple parameters, but it's "situational".
